# Does c++ realloc function applies delete operation for old data block if moving data to different block?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

The function may move the memory block to a new location, in which case the new location is returned.
For example I have a pointer to an array:

```
int *arr; // somewhere next it initialized, filled with elements and etc
```

Somewhere I need to:

```
void* location = realloc(arr, NEW_SIZE);
```

What will happen with old memory block place?

If realloc return pointer that not math to arr, should i use next code?:

```
delete arr;
arr = (int*)location;
```

Comment: @Component10: Make it an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: but arr was initialized with new like that: arr = new int[SIZE];

Comment: If you allocate using `new[size]`, you should deallocate using `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Comment: @wilx: Fair comment - answer made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[realloc(void *ptr, size_t new_size)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) requires the given area of memory that `ptr` points to to *be previously allocated by malloc(), calloc() or realloc() and not yet freed with free(), otherwise, the results are undefined.*

Use **realloc** only with **malloc**, **calloc** or another **realloc** and clean it up with **free**.
In C++ use always **new** with **delete** and **new[]** with **delete[]**.

Answer (score 7):

The function `realloc` is inherited from good old C. It does not run destructors or do any other C++ magic. It can also only be applied to blocks allocated using `malloc` (and friends) -- it *can not be used for blocks allocated using 'new'*.

Comment: oh so... thanks for clearing this things out for me. i didn't even test my application for run-ability, because run into that question

Answer (score 4):

Rule #1: dont mix new/delete with malloc/free.

If you're allocating with `malloc()` in the first place and you need a bigger heap space then you need to call `realloc()` which will return you a new pointer which may not map to the same memory areas as `arr` therefore you should not use it.

Free malloc'ed/realloc'ed space with `free`

Comment: If you wish, you can also allocate new piece of memory with `realloc(NULL, size)` and get rid of `malloc` :-)

Comment: And also get rid of `free` with `realloc(ptr, 0)`. Some C memory management abusing :-)

Comment: That's not abuse, it's intended that way so libraries can be passed a single memory allocation function for custom memory handling.